# How to access/override "vs-dark" or "vs" uiTheme colors

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, themes

There are some severe theming limitations when VSCode lumps themes into only two uiTheme's:
"**vs**" (for all light themes) or "**vs-dark**" (for all dark theme)s.

This doesn't allow people to make VSCode color themes that don't fall into either category.  I would like to know how to access and override uiTheme colors via a custom extension to allow more interesting color themes. Maybe, this can be done via a custom CSS? If so, I'm hoping someone could give me an example of how to do this.

EDIT:  It looks like this resource is stored in:

```
C:/Users/micha/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.css
```

It looks like I need a css with the [vscode-custom-css](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) extension.  However, I have no idea how to determine the name of the resource I would like to customize.  I know I might need to use the developer mode in VSCode.  However, I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this all out.  I tried both [vscode-custom-css](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) as well as [vscode-vibrancy](https://github.com/EYHN/vscode-vibrancy) VScode extensions they both allowed me to inject my own custom CSS code to modify parts to VSCode that normally wouldn't be customizable. I started off by replacing VSCode's code folding icons.  I then ended up using the Vibrancy extension's code since it didn't produce a "corrupted installation" message in VSCode like the other extension did.  Also, it has a Vibrancy (blur transparency) feature as a bonus. I then integrated that code (MIT opensource) in my own theme extension.

I used VSCode's Developer mode to inspect its existing CSS; and, make a custom CSS.  Below is the CSS I used:

```css
body {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .margin-view-overlays .folding,
body {
background-image: url(../themes/images/arrow_down.png);
}
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .margin-view-overlays .folding.collapsed,
body {
background-image: url(../themes/images/arrow_right.png);
}

.monaco-editor .inline-folded,
body {
background-image: url(../themes/images/fold.png);
}
```

Here's the link my VSCode Extension:

**[MKANET Theme V2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MKANET.mkanet-theme-v2)**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For [custom themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme), `dark` vs `light` mainly means the following:

- The base set of [theme colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) used. Custom themes override these base colors
- Which variant of icons to use (icons that work well on a darker background vs ones that are designed for a lighter background light). Theme can customize some icon colors too
- Which category theme is listed in when the user is selecting a theme (`dark` vs `light`)

But `dark` vs `light` in no way limits what colors a custom theme can or cannot use. A `light` theme for example could set every UI color with various shades of dark grey, or it could use a neon rainbow of colors.

In short: you do not need to create a new category of themes beyond `dark` or `light`, nor should you need to use custom css.

Comment: Yes, I already know what the predefined dark/light UI theme elements are; as, I already published an extension theme (using the dark UI base theme). It looks like there's an extension that does exactly what I'm looking for:  https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css.  I just need to see if it's something I can include in my own theme without depending on the vscode custom CSS extension.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Set the colors programmatically?

Comment: VSCode themes have certain element colors that aren't themeable.  These unthemeable elements presume ALL components of a theme are either "dark" OR "light".  Hence, it's very difficult to design themes that have a "dark" sidebar and "dark" panel with a light editor background or the other way around.  Unthemeable elements like code folding icons, split editor/split terminal icons, command-palette shortcut cord icon colors, etc, all come in either a dark OR light compatible base "set" which can't be mixed and matched or defined independently.

Comment: I need assistance to control the color to these unthemeable elements via my theme extension (same method that's used in the VSCode-Custom-CSS extension).  The only thing I can do is try to figure out how this extension does it or ask how to do it here.  For example, how to change the color of the code-folding icons in my theme.